# POSTGRESQL Subquery with a Order by Function does not return values

Tags: postgresql, function, subquery

I have the following code that does not return values to the select because of my order by (Function)

```
Select sub.enrollmentseqnumemp ,sub.membercodedep,a.Subscriber_ID
    From elan_staging.check_register_1 a
        Left join (
            Select enrollmentseqnumemp ,membercodedep
            from elan.elig
            ORDER BY public.idx(array['e','s','1','2','3','4','5'],membercodedep) Limit 1)  sub
    On sub.enrollmentseqnumemp=a.Subscriber_ID
    

    |  enrollmentseqnumemp  |  membercodedep  |  Subscriber_ID  |       
    |:----------------------|:----------------|:----------------|
    |       [null]          |      [null]     |    "462852"     |
    |       [null]          |      [null]     |    "462852"     |
    |       [null]          |      [null]     |    "407742"     |
```

If I run it without the Order By function, it works correctly

```
         Select sub.enrollmentseqnumemp 
         ,sub.membercodedep,a.Subscriber_ID
         From elan_staging.check_register_1 a
            Left join (
               Select enrollmentseqnumemp ,membercodedep
               from elan.elig
               ORDER BY 1) sub
         On sub.enrollmentseqnumemp=a.Subscriber_ID 
         Limit 1


    |  enrollmentseqnumemp  |  membercodedep  |  Subscriber_ID  |       
    |:----------------------|:----------------|:----------------|
    |       111111          |        e        |    "462852"     |
    |       222222          |        3        |    "462852"     |
    |       333333          |        s        |    "407742"     |
```

Code for the function from the Postgres snippets repository:

```
    CREATE FUNCTION idx(anyarray varchar (1) ARRAY[4], anyelement varchar (1))
        RETURNS int AS 
    $$
    SELECT i FROM (
            SELECT generate_series(array_lower($1,1),array_upper($1,1))
        ) g(i)
        WHERE $1[i] = $2
        LIMIT 1;
    $$ LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;
```

Is there a way to fix it so that it returns the values?

Comment: One has a LIMIT, and the other does not.

Comment: With or without Limit 1 on the second query, the second query returns values to the Select. The first one does not.

Comment: Now you have put the LIMIT on the wrong spot, and your example output surely cannot be obtained with that query.

Answer (score 1):

The first query as you have written it can return non-NULLs out of elig only for the one row with globally smallest value of `public.idx(...)`.  If you want values for the smallest `public.idx(...)` within each enrollmentseqnumemp, you could use `distinct on`, like :

```
Select sub.enrollmentseqnumemp ,sub.membercodedep,a.Subscriber_ID
    From check_register_1 a
        Left join (
            Select distinct(enrollmentseqnumemp) enrollmentseqnumemp, membercodedep, public.idx(array['e','s','1','2','3','4','5'],membercodedep)
            from elig
            ORDER BY enrollmentseqnumemp, public.idx(array['e','s','1','2','3','4','5'],membercodedep))  sub
    On sub.enrollmentseqnumemp=a.Subscriber_ID;
```